# Issues getting column width set when creating a csv file from Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, format, export

I am having to update 500+ machines at work not knowing the patching status of them and what they will need patched. This will just be a script that will tell me which machines are online or offline so I know what to target with other scripts that are yet to be written.

This will output to a CSV file and it can be opened successfully with all of the data in the proper columns.

How do I get the column width of the columns in the CSV file to be a set size or autosized to the data in the columns?

I can get the data formatted the way I would like in Powershell. it will display properly onscreen. All of the ways I have tried to export it do not provide the correct result.

Also if possible, can background color, font, bold, etc be set from powershell and sent to the CSV file? Future scripts that I will have will be creating CSV files with 50+ columns and over 500 rows.

```
# Setting Time Variable
$Script_Time = (Get-Date -Format MM-dd-yyyy--HH-mm)

# XXXXXXXX Path mapping for Computer Names, Ping Logs, CSV Name
$Root_Path = $env:USERPROFILE + "\xxxx-Working-Path----\"
    $Computer_Names_Path = $root_Path + "Computer_Names\"
        $Computer_Names_File = $Computer_Names_Path + "\ComputerNames_Working.txt"
    $Ping_Logs_Path  = $Root_Path + "Logs\Ping_Logs\"
        $Log_Csv_Name = $Ping_Logs_Path + "Ping Results--" + $Script_Time + ".csv"

# Blanking/Setting needed variables
$Path_Result    = ""
$Ping_Result    = ""
$Name           = ""
$Machine_Status = ""
$Total_Count    = 0
$Online_Count   = 0
$Offline_Count  = 0

# Gathering Computer Names from text file
$List_Of_Computers = Get-Content "$Computer_Names_File"

# Array creation for CSV output
$Results_Array = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

# Testing to see if folders exist
If (Test-Path $Computer_Names_Path){
    $Path_Result = "Computer Names Path Exists"
    Write-Output $Path_Result
    }   
    Else{
    $Path_Result = "Computer Names Path Does Not Exist"
    Write-Output $Path_Result
    Pause
    }

If (Test-Path $Ping_Logs_Path){
    $Path_Result = "Ping Logs Csv Path Exists"
    Write-Output $Path_Result
    }        
    Else{
    $Path_Result = "Ping Logs Csv Path Does Not Exist"
    Write-Output $Path_Result
    Pause
    }

# Loop to gather online status of each machine
Foreach ($Name in $List_Of_Computers) {

    # Test for True result
    If (test-connection -computername $name -buffersize 16 -count 1 -quiet){
        $Ping_Result = "Online"
        $Online_Count = $Online_Count + 1
        }

        # Test for false result
        Else{
        $Ping_Result = "Offline"
        $Offline_Count = $Offline_Count + 1
        }

        # Displays Online status and adds to CSV Array
        $Machine_Status = $Name + "," + $Ping_Result + "," + (Get-Date -Format MM-dd-yyyy--HH-mm-ss)
        Write-Output $Machine_Status
        [void]$Results_Array.add($Machine_Status)
}

# Total machine count
$Total_Count = $Results_Array.Count

# Adding Information to Top 2 rows in Array
$Results_Array.Insert(0,"No of Machines: $Total_Count,Online Total: $Online_Count,Offline Total: $Offline_Count")
$Results_Array.Insert(1,"Computer Name,Online Status,Timestamp")

# Sends Array to CSV File
set-content $Log_Csv_Name -Value $Results_Array
```

EDIT

Applied what I had to a Excel Application output. Thanks for pointing my in that direction. It is working perfectly. Just need to finish fine tuning the formatting that I desire and learn how to save it with Powershell. Both, I assume, I will be able to research easily.

Here is the new script I have come up with after researching and applying what I found. Hopefully it will help others if they stumble upon this.

```
# Setting Time Variable
Write-Output "Setting Time Variable" ""
$Script_Time = (Get-Date -Format MM-dd-yyyy--HH-mm)

# XXXXXXXX Path Mapping for Computer Names and Ping Logs
Write-Output "Setting Path Variable" ""
$Root_Path = $env:USERPROFILE + "\XXXXXXXXXXX\"
    $Computer_Names_Path = $root_Path + "Computer_Names\"
        $Computer_Names_File = $Computer_Names_Path + "\ComputerNames_Working.txt"
    $Ping_Logs_Path  = $Root_Path + "Logs\Ping_Logs\"

# Testing to see if Folders Exist
Write-Output "Testing to see if Folder Paths exist" ""
If (Test-Path $Computer_Names_Path){
    $Path_Result = "Computer Names Path Exists"
    Write-Output $Path_Result
    }   
Else{
    $Path_Result = "Computer Names Path Does Not Exist"
    Write-Output $Path_Result
    Pause
}

If (Test-Path $Ping_Logs_Path){
    $Path_Result = "Ping Logs Csv Path Exists"
    Write-Output $Path_Result ""
    }        
Else{
    $Path_Result = "Ping Logs Csv Path Does Not Exist"
    Write-Output $Path_Result
    Pause
}

# Creating Excel Application
Write-Output "Creating Excel and Setting up the Sheet" ""
$New_Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

# Makes Excel Visable
$New_Excel.Application.Visible = $true
$New_Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

# Creating Excel WorkBook
$New_Book = $New_Excel.Workbooks.Add()

# Sets the Worksheet and Names it
$New_Sheet = $New_Book.Worksheets.Item(1)
$New_Sheet.name = "Ping Results--" + (Get-Date -Format MM-dd-yyyy--HH-mm)

# Selects the Worksheet
$New_Sheet.Activate()

# Blanking/Setting Needed Variables
Write-Output "Setting Start Variables" ""
$Path_Result    = ""
$Ping_Result    = ""
$Name           = ""
$Machine_Status = ""
$Total_Count    = 0
$Online_Count   = 0
$Offline_Count  = 0
$Row            = 1
$Column         = 1

# Creates the Title for the Sheet
Write-Output "Creating Title" ""
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column) = "Ping Results"
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column).Font.Size = 21
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column).HorizontalAlignment = -4108
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column).Font.Bold = $true

# Merging Cells for the Title
$New_Sheet.Range("A1:c1").Merge()

# Skipping Two Rows to leave space for Totals to be added at the end
$row = $Row + 2

# Creating Column Headers for the Data
Write-Output "Creating Column Headers" ""
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column) = "Computer Name"
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column).Font.Size = 16
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column).Font.ColorIndex = 1
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column).Font.Bold = $True
$column++
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column) = "Online Status"
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column).Font.Size = 16
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column).Font.ColorIndex = 1
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column).Font.Bold = $True
$column++
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column) = "Timestamp"
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column).Font.Size = 16
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column).Font.ColorIndex = 1
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item($Row,$Column).Font.Bold = $True

# Sets the Column and Row for the First Set of Data
$Row = $Row + 1
$Column = 1

# Gathers the List of Computers
Write-Output "Gathering Computer Names" ""
$List_Of_Computers = Get-Content "$Computer_Names_File"

# Loop to get the status of each machine
Write-Output "Gathering Data from each Computer" ""
Write-Output "Computer Name     Online Status          Timestamp"
Foreach ($Name in $List_Of_Computers){
    If (test-connection -computername $name -buffersize 16 -count 1 -quiet){
        $Ping_Result = "Online"
        $Online_Count = $Online_Count + 1
        }
    Else{
        $Ping_Result = "Offline"
        $Offline_Count = $Offline_Count + 1
        }

    $Machine_Status = $Name + "        " + $Ping_Result + "         " + (Get-Date -Format MM-dd-yyyy--HH-mm-ss)
    Write-Output $Machine_Status

    $New_Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column) = $Name
    $column = $Column + 1

    $New_Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column) = $Ping_Result
    $Column = $Column + 1

    $New_Sheet.Cells.Item($row,$column) = (Get-Date -Format MM-dd-yyyy--HH-mm-ss)
    $Row = $row + 1
    $Column = 1
}

# Adding Totals Information to Row 2
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item(2,1) = "# of Machines: " + $List_Of_Computers.Count
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item(2,2) = "Online Total: " + $Online_Count
$New_Sheet.Cells.Item(2,3) = "Offline Total: " + $Offline_Count
```

Comment: CSV files are data with commas, they have no structure or support for formatting, not column width nor font styling nor anything else. You can't; if you want a pretty report you'll need to generate an XLSX file or HTML or something.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply TessellatingHeckler. I will look into XLSX aspect now and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Check out the     `select-object` and     `export-csv` cmdlets.  It won't do coloured fonts as it only creates a csv, but your column width are autosized and much easier

Comment: One way is to convert your output that is generated in `csv` format to `xlsx`and then proceed with formatting and stuff. Check out this [link](https://code.adonline.id.au/csv-to-xlsx-powershell/)